# Host mountpoint inside docker volume inconsistency

Tags: linux, docker, mount, cgroup

I have a simple setup, where I bind-mount a host's folder in a container.

```
docker run --rm -it -v /mnt:/mnt ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Then I mount some other file systems to the host's folder. Mount points appear on the container side, but corresponding mounted file systems do not.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/a
sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/a
```

If I start a container with something pre-mounted under host's folder, they will be visible.

I believe I am missing something about how Linux cgroups work. Can anybody shed some light on what is going on?

I am running docker `17.03.0-ce`

Answer (score 2):

Newer docker versions introduce more CLI options for volume control. Now one can specify [options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) for mounting. Using option `shared` on a host-bound volume allows for mount propagations from host's mount namespace into container:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /mnt:/mnt:shared ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Unmounts done inside the container will propagate back to the host